# redirecting in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

When someone comes to www.example.com he should go to my root folder but the subdomain is other that www e.g. abc.example.com he should redirected to abc.example.com/folder1 without changing the url

Answer (score 0):

ok.

So when you go on your website without redirect at the moment you go abc.example.com/folder1

Maybe you can try:

RewriteRule ^folder1$ http://www.example.com/ [L]

Comment: but it will also redirect www.example.com also to /folder1